# How can I filter document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a `query` collection in mongodb which contains document in the below format :

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("61aced92ede..."),
    query : "How to solve...?",
    answer : []
    is_solved : false
}
```

Now, I want to filter the documents with the following condition

1. filter all documents that are not solved. (`is_solved : true`)
2. filter "n" number of document that are solved.

So, That result will have all unsolved documents and only 10 solved documents in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to create two ways: The document solved, and document not solved.
- Into each way do the necessary `$match` and `$limit` the solved documents.
- Then concatenate the values using `$concatArrays`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "not_solved": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "is_solved": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "solved": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "is_solved": true
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "result": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$not_solved",
          "$solved"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j8sHEP-Kvqs) where I've used `$limit: 1` to see easier.

Also, if you want, you can add `$unwind` at the end of the aggregation to get values at the top level like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CQyuklpHXx7)

Comment: I was looking for some hint. But thanks for this much effort, specially to playground.